# How to unset a dynamically applied point color in a Highcharts pie chart?

Tags: highcharts

I want to be able to toggle colors on and off Points in a Highcharts pie chart.

Here's the sequence of operations

1. First I will render the chart
2. Next I will update the series.point color using point.update

   `this.chart.series[0].points[0].update({color: 'red'});`
3. Then I want to unset the color I applied in step 2

Aside from caching the original color. I have tried

```
this.chart.series[0].points[0].update({color: void 0});
this.chart.series[0].points[0].update({color: null});
```

I've tested that this works on on series.update, such as

```
this.chart.series[0].update({color: void 0})
```

How can I unset the color on Point?

Currently my workaround is to redraw the whole chart! Feel like this might be a bug in Highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/6r0poq3k/) demo to show steps as required

```
// Initiate the chart
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  }]
});

// function for update color
function update() {

  chart.series[0].points[0].update({
    color: 'red'
  });
};
// function for unset color
function unsetColor() {
  chart.series[0].points[0].update({
    color: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).input
  });
}
```